# sed solaris 5.10

Tags: regex, unix, sed, solaris

Hi I am trying to write a script to parse some html files to make a job a bit easier, but I'm having no luck, I've tried reading other threads and manuals to no avail. I seem to get stuck with circular brackets.

I want to replace all appearances of:

`$FORMTOP("2")$` with `$FORMTOP("3")$`

`$WHITE*("5")$` with `$WHITE*("10")$`

`</b>` with `</strong>`

`<tr><td`  with `<tr> newline, tab <td`

delete occurrences of `<td></td>`

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Do you want to delete all occurrences of <td></td> with nothing in between?  Do you want to delete everything in a <ts>.*</td> construction, but only when it appears after the 3 specific lines in the example?  What is the purpose of the 4 line block of code (7 with blank lines) in the question?

Comment: Yes I want to delete all occurrences of <td></td> with nothing in between. I used code because i couldn't display arrows properly. Every occurence of <tr><td* I want <td* to appear tabbed on the next line, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sed you will have to put a new line (put a "\" and hit enter) and tab spaces (press spacebar 8 times) manually in the replacement section.

```
[jaypal@MBP-13~/temp] sed 's/<tr><td/<tr>\
        <td/g' test123
<tr>
        <td 

<tr>
        <td
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for certain that this will work on Solaris, as I don't have it available anymore, but I'm using Sun-Solaris std sed commands with nothing fancy, I think this should work.

```
{
cat <<-EOS
\$FORMTOP("2")$
\$WHITE*("5")$
</b>
<tr><td
EOS
} |sed '
s/\$FORMTOP("2")\$/\$FORMTOP("3")\$/g
s/\$WHITE\*("5")\$/\$WHITE\*("10")\$/g
s/<\/b>/\<\/strong>/g
/<tr><td/{
  s/<td//
  a\
    <td

}
'

#output 
$FORMTOP("3")$
$WHITE*("10")$
</strong>
<tr>
        <td
```

For this testing harness, using `{ cat <<-EOS ... EOS }`, I had to escape the '$' that where being interpreted as env vars by the shell. If you put the test data in a file, be sure to remove the '\'s in front of the '$'s.

**EDIT** Also, stuff that looks indented in sed, is indented with spaces except for the  char just before your final `<td`.

Also, as you wrote 'I've tried reading other threads',you did find the S.O. number one post concerning [fixing XML with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), right?

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that, everything works apart from the tab appearing after, it just puts the <td on a newline. I can work with that though, thanks :)

Comment: hm... so the line in question should look like $sp$sp$tab<td , where of course $sp = a space char and $tab = a tab char OR you don't really need the spaces, they are included as eye candy ;-) Good luck. (It worked for me :-/)!